# Integers having the same digits as their prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Say an integer is "digitally conservative" in base $b$ if the set of its digits coincides with the set of the digits of its prime factors, like $37127=137\times 271$ in base $10$, and denote by $Dig_{b}(x)$ the number of such integers not exceeding $x$. Can one give an asymptotics for the latter?

Comment: The vast majority of numbers have all digits in their base b-expansion, and so almost always the set of digits of a number is the same as the set of digits of its prime factors: all of the digits.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would you happen to have a proof?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN it seems like a straightforward counting argument, and likely more appropriate for MSE.

Comment: Ok, I'll consider asking there then. But I must confess that, as straightforward as it might be, it doesn't quite follow a geodesic in the Riemaniann manifold of my mind.